# Can't find lib which provides libneon.so.25

Tags: yum, libraries

I'm running `yum whatprovides libneon.so.25`, but can't find any library that provides this. Am I missing something?

Comment: can you try `yum whatprovides libneon` ?

Comment: @edvinas.me: `libneon` not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to provide **full path** like following example:

```
[root@sys1]# yum whatprovides /usr/lib64/libkdeinit4_konsole.so
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
el6x64/filelists                                                                                                                                                                                                      | 3.5 MB     00:00     
6:kdebase-4.3.4-4.el6.x86_64 : KDE Core Files
Repo        : el6x64
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libkdeinit4_konsole.so



6:kdebase-4.3.4-4.el6.x86_64 : KDE Core Files
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: /usr/lib64/libkdeinit4_konsole.so
```

**Or** file you want is **not available** in your yum repository server/s.

**EDIT:** You can install `libneon.so.25` using http://rpm.pbone.net. And search for `neon`, also select architecture and OS option/s using Advanced RPM Search option. Download appropriate rpm file (Do not download `neon-devel-<version>.rpm`, only `neon-<verion>.rpm` will work) and install that.

Comment: for some reason I need to install this particular version   `libneon.so.25`.How can I install `libneon.so.25`?

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Hi Tejas! can I try it in online VM.Googling gave me Koding.com but it's ubuntu and I need centOS.Can't seem to find an option to change OS.

Comment: I think `libneon.so.25` is not available, you can try installing `libneon.so.27`, which is available on site I mentioned. And then even if problem persist just try symlink `ln -s libneon.so.27 libneon.so.25`.

Comment: Hi Tejas! I did `ln -s libneon.so.27 libneon.so.25` in `/usr/lib/` directory.But still `yum whatprovides libneon.so.25` says `No Matches found`.

Comment: 1st you need to install libneon.so.27 from its rpm and then symlink using `ln -s`. Don't bother about `yum whatprovides`

Comment: I already have `libneon.so.27` installed and `yum whatprovides libneon.so.27` gives me `neon-0.29.3-3.el6_4.i686`

Comment: This is of 32 bit architecture. Which architecture you are using? If you are using 64bit then you may need to install neon-0.29.3-3.el6_4.x86_64.rpm

Comment: I'm using 32bit architecture Tejas.

Comment: Why you need `ln -s libneon.so.25` ?

Comment: While trying to install subversion 1.7 with rpm.It wanted this lib.May I missed something.It is working now :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your system repos do not have any packages contains file `libneon.so.25`. You can use shell glob to match file name when searching with `yum whatprovides`.

Here is result in my `Fedora 20`:

```
$ yum whatprovides */libneon*
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
neon-0.30.0-2.fc20.i686 : An HTTP and WebDAV client library
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libneon.so.27.3.0
Filename    : /usr/lib/libneon.so.27



neon-0.30.0-2.fc20.x86_64 : An HTTP and WebDAV client library
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libneon.so.27.3.0
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libneon.so.27



neon-devel-0.30.0-2.fc20.i686 : Development libraries and C header files for the
                              : neon library
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libneon.la
Filename    : /usr/lib/libneon.so



neon-devel-0.30.0-2.fc20.x86_64 : Development libraries and C header files for
                                : the neon library
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libneon.la
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libneon.so



neon-0.30.0-2.fc20.x86_64 : An HTTP and WebDAV client library
Repo        : @koji-override-0/$releasever
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libneon.so.27.3.0
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libneon.so.27
```

Comment: for some reason I need to install this particular version   `libneon.so.25`.How can I install `libneon.so.25`?

Comment: By using different version of package. Whatever program has libneon as requirement it should state which version it needs exactly.